# Email validator not working properly in django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am not using django forms here and I am validating field with ajax/jquery but this code is not working properly.

If I enter the correct email it displays the error message but if i enter the invalid email then it doesn't display the error.

Also this `validate_email(request.GET.get('email', ''))` always returns None.

views

```
class ValidateEmailField(View):

    def get(self, request):
        email = validate_email(request.GET.get('email', ''))
        print(email)
        data = {}

        if not email:
            data = {
                'error_message': 'Invalid Email'
            }
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

template

```
dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          if (data.error_message) {
            $(".error").text(data.error_message).show();
            $('#id_btn').prop("disabled", true);

          }
          else {
       $(".error").text(data.error_message).hide();
       $('#id_btn').prop("disabled", false);
      }
```

Comment: Just a note, nothing is stopping you (I'd encourage it) from using a form to validate the JSON data you're posting. Or if you're doing this a lot, you might want to consider using Django REST Framework.

Comment: First, check whether `request.GET.get('email', '')` have the exact same data that you are sent by ajax. If its ok, then check the logic of `validate_email()` function

Comment: @ArakkalAbu i checked it `request.GET.get('email')` has same value I entered but `validate_email` is returning None

Comment: @ArakkalAbu but it raises a validation error in the console when I entered the invalid email. How can I show that message in my template through ajax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a proper `status_code` to trigger the error callback in frontend

```
class ValidateEmailField(View):

   def get(self, request):
       email = request.GET.get('email', '')
       try:
            validate_email(email)
       except ValidationError:
            ...
            message: 'Invalid Email'
            status_code = 400
            return JsonResponse({'message':message }, status=status_code)
       # default status_code is 200
       return JsonResponse({'message': 'success'})
```

`status_code=4xx`, in your template, the `error callback` will be triggered, you can register your callback here

```
$.ajax({
    success: ...
      error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
         // error callback, run your code here
         console.log(jqXhr.responseText);
})
```

#### UPDATE

source of `validate_email`, **`validate_email()`** will trigger **`__call__`** method, which will return either `None` or `ValidationError`, that's why your code `email=validate_email(...)` email always is `None` even your email is validated

```
class EmailValidator:
    message = _('Enter a valid email address.')
    code = 'invalid
    ...

    def __call__(self, value):
        if not value or '@' not in value:
            raise ValidationError(self.message, code=self.code)

        user_part, domain_part = value.rsplit('@', 1)

        if not self.user_regex.match(user_part):
            raise ValidationError(self.message, code=self.code)

        if (domain_part not in self.domain_allowlist and
                not self.validate_domain_part(domain_part)):
            # Try for possible IDN domain-part
            try:
                domain_part = punycode(domain_part)
            except UnicodeError:
                pass
            else:
                if self.validate_domain_part(domain_part):
                    return
            raise ValidationError(self.message, code=self.code)
```

Comment: I think the logic of `validate_email` is not working in my view. When i enter invalid email it displays error in my the console saying not a valid address.

Comment: @user12428848 that's because `validate_email` always return `None` or `raise Validation`, it won't return any email in your case, but if fails validation, you can catch that exception and rewrite the message

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. Now I am getting `Bad request` error message instead I want the message that I write above `Invalid Email`.

Comment: does it necessary in the `GET` request as well ?

Comment: @user12428848 `Bad Rquest` is due to the status_code 400, I am not sure, can you `console.log(errorMessage.message)`

Comment: `console.log(jqXhr) or console.log(jqXhr.responseText)`, I am not sure where it resides

Comment: `{"message": "Invalid  Email."}` in console with responseText

Comment: finalmente it succed, you can now `parse` the json, and report the error yourself

Comment: I tried `json.loads(message)` but the error is `the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict `

Comment: @user12428848 in browser, I think you should use `JSON.parse()`, while in python, you can use `json.loads(s)` and s should be in format `'{"message": "data"}'`

Comment: from where I should import `JSON`

Comment: @user12428848 its available in browser, test in your console `JSON.parse('{"a":"b"}')`